# Публикация UWP приложения для ограниченного количества пользователей

Tags: uwp, microsoft-store

Как выполнить публикацию UWP приложения только "для своих", чтобы видно было только заказчику приложения. В магазине видно всем. Может можно для UWP использовать простой установщик, типа ClickOnce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно распространять только среди тех, у кого есть ключ. Можно собрать релизную сборку без публикации и отдавать ее. Project - Store - Create app packages и там, где спросят хотите ли опубликовать выбрать "нет".

Comment: Спасибо огромное